# How can I pass the value from MDCSelect to the $_POST variable?

Tags: javascript

How can I pass the value from 'mdc-select__selected-text' to PHP $_POST?

[Google Material Web Select - Docs](https://material.io/components/web/catalog/input-controls/select-menus/)

Do I have to create an extra 'hidden input' here and save the value via js? So I have it when sending the form in the $ _Post variable?

```
<div class="mdc-select" role="listbox">
  <div class="mdc-select__surface" tabindex="0">
    <div class="mdc-select__label">Pick a Food Group</div>
    <div class="mdc-select__selected-text"></div>
    <div class="mdc-select__bottom-line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mdc-menu mdc-select__menu">
    <ul class="mdc-list mdc-menu__items">
      <li class="mdc-list-item" role="option" tabindex="0">
        Bread, Cereal, Rice, and Pasta
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-list-item" role="option" tabindex="0">
        Vegetables
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-list-item" role="option" tabindex="0">
        Fruit
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-list-item" role="option" tabindex="0">
        Milk, Yogurt, and Cheese
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-list-item" role="option" tabindex="0">
        Meat, Poultry, Fish, Dry Beans, Eggs, and Nuts
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-list-item" role="option" tabindex="0">
        Fats, Oils, and Sweets
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code here!

Comment: https://codepen.io/QJan84/pen/zRmyeO

Comment: _In your Question_, you already provided a link to it

Comment: I have updated my question. I'm happy about help.